# canvas pie chart in 3d using html js j

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a working 2d pie chart created using canvas2d by HTML and JavaScript. Is it possible to have in 3d the below same thing by using HTML, CSS, js or jQuery too. If not, is there any advanced graphics options such as splitting the pie chart and displaying it but 3d is preferred. Thanks in advance.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
nvas.height;

ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.font = '12px verdana';
ctx.textAlign='center';
ctx.textBaseline='middle';

var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
var myColor = ['green','blue'];
var myData = [chv2,chs2];
var labels =["LA:" +chv2+"%","LB:" +chs2+"%"];
var cx = 150;
var cy = 150;
var radius = 100;

pieChart(myData, myColor);

function pieChart(data, colors) {

  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    total += data[i];
  }

  var sweeps = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    sweeps.push(data[i] / total * PI2);
  }

  var accumAngle = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < sweeps.length; i++) {
    drawWedge(accumAngle, accumAngle + sweeps[i], colors[i], labels[i]);
    accumAngle += sweeps[i];
  }

}

function drawWedge(startAngle, endAngle, fill, label) {

  // draw the wedge
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(cx, cy);
  ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, startAngle, endAngle, false);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = fill;
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();

  // draw the label
  var midAngle = startAngle + (endAngle - startAngle) / 2;
  var labelRadius = radius * .75;
  var x = cx + (labelRadius) * Math.cos(midAngle);
  var y = cy + (labelRadius) * Math.sin(midAngle);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fillText(label, x, y);

}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300" style="display:none;" >
    This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
    </canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this [example](http://codepen.io/pankajparashar/pen/fspAH) using html, css, javascript:

```
var chart;
var legend;

var chartData = [{
    country: "Lithuania",
    value: 260}, 
    /* more values ... */];

AmCharts.ready(function() {
    // PIE CHART
    chart = new AmCharts.AmPieChart();
    chart.dataProvider = chartData;
    chart.titleField = "country";
    chart.valueField = "value";
    chart.outlineColor = "";
    chart.outlineAlpha = 0.8;
    chart.outlineThickness = 2;
    // this makes the chart 3D
    chart.depth3D = 20;
    chart.angle = 30;

    // WRITE
    chart.write("chartdiv");
});
```

Comment: sorry it will have an amchart watermark so i need someother with no watermark